# Why is My Code not showing results

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help with this code. The code basically asks to do 1 of 2 things. If a postcode is entered then the code does a radius search and searches the database for any rows containing the postcodes in the array. However if a city / street is entered I want to the code to bypass this and just search for rows containing them details.  The Code is below.

```
    $postcode = str_replace( '+', '%20', $postcode );

$conn = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','user','pass') or die('db connect error:'.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('database', $conn) or die('could not select database');

$sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM postcodelatlng WHERE postcode ='".$postcode."'";
$result = mysql_query($sqlstring);   

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$lng = $row["longitude"] / 180 * M_PI;
$lat = $row["latitude"] / 180 * M_PI;

mysql_free_result($result);    

$sqlstring2 = "SELECT DISTINCT 
  postcodelatlng.postcode,
  (
    6367.41 * SQRT(
      2 * (
        1- COS(RADIANS(postcodelatlng.latitude)) * COS(".$lat.") * (
          SIN(RADIANS(postcodelatlng.longitude)) * SIN(".$lng.") + COS(RADIANS(postcodelatlng.longitude)) * COS(".$lng.")
        ) - SIN(RADIANS(postcodelatlng.latitude)) * SIN(".$lat.")
      )
    )
  ) AS Distance 
FROM
  postcodelatlng AS postcodelatlng 
HAVING Distance <= '".$radius."'
ORDER BY Distance ";

$result1 = mysql_query($sqlstring2) or die('query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        if ($row['postcode'] == 0){

            $sqlstring3="SELECT * FROM property_details WHERE  street = '".$postcode."' OR address3 = '".$postcode."' OR county = '".$postcode."' ";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sqlstring3) or die('Query Failed: ' . mysql_error());
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
            echo ' 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="viewprop.php?id='.$row2[0].'">
                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 inner col-xs-12" align="justify">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                            <img src="images/rentals/1.jpg" width="80%" height="80%" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                            <h2>'. $row2[13]. '</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                            <h4 class="rbgclr2">£'. $row2[2]. ' Per Month</h3>
                            <h5 class="rbgclr1">£'. $row2[3]. ' Deposit</h4>
                            <br />
                            <p>Bedrooms = '. $row2[4]. '</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
            <br />';
        }
        }
        else {
            $sqlstring4="SELECT * FROM property_details WHERE postcode = '".$row['postcode']."' ";
    $result3 = mysql_query($sqlstring4) or die('Query Failed: ' . mysql_error());
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
            echo ' 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="viewprop.php?id='.$row2[0].'">
                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 inner col-xs-12" align="justify">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                            <img src="images/rentals/1.jpg" width="80%" height="80%" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                            <h2>'. $row2[13]. '</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                            <h4 class="rbgclr2">£'. $row2[2]. ' Per Month</h3>
                            <h5 class="rbgclr1">£'. $row2[3]. ' Deposit</h4>
                            <br />
                            <p>Bedrooms = '. $row2[4]. '</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
            <br />';
        }
    }
    }




mysqli_close($con); 

?>
```

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to rasie your content quality

Comment: Hello @darren to stack overflow. Please check this link to find how to write a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also check this one too that shows you how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that will help you get your questions answered quickly http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Good luck.

Comment: Do you mean if city is entered then the query is "SELECT * FROM postcodelatlng"?

Comment: No, basically, if postcode is entered, it checks a postcodelatlng database for all postcodes within a certain distance, Once it has them it then checks the results from that against the property_details table. However if a city, street, town etc is entered it just goes straight to check the property_details table.